# Getting invalid number of arguments despite inputting the correct number

Tags: python, invalid-argument

```
import numpy as np

class Body(object): # Class for planets / moons / asteroids
    
    def __init__(self, mass, velocity, position):
        
        self.mass = mass  # Defining variables
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.position = position
        
        
    def move(self, force, t):
        self.velocity = np.add(self.velocity + force * t / self.mass) # Code to move with time t
        self.position = np.add(self.position + self.velocity * t)
        return self
        
def main():
    
    mars = Body(6.4185*10**23, np.array([0, 0]), np.array([0, 0]))
    mars.move(np.array([10, 10]), 10) # Force defined to be [10, 10] and time 10
    
    
main()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\p\Documents\dev\sodump\npadd.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\p\Documents\dev\sodump\npadd.py", line 20, in main
    mars.move(np.array([10, 10]), 10) # Force defined to be [10, 10] and time 10
  File "c:\Users\p\Documents\dev\sodump\npadd.py", line 13, in move
    self.velocity = np.add(self.velocity + force * t / self.mass) # Code to move with time t
ValueError: invalid number of arguments
```

Comment: please add the error stacktrace as well

Comment: What you probably meant was `np.add(self.position, self.velocity * t)` instead of `np.add(self.position + self.velocity * t)`? That function takes two arguments and adds them. You were doing the add using the regular `+` operator. [Here's](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) the `np.add` docs

Comment: looks like [np.add](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html#numpy.add) takes two arguments but you only provided one.

Comment: Further, given that the `+` operator is available, you probably want to write `self.position = self.position + self.velocity * t` or even `self.position += self.velocity * t`; much easier to read than the `np.add(...)` notation...

Comment: Thanks Paul, works as intended, face palm

Comment: Please tell us what your questoin is, apar from just having an error code

Answer (score 0):

The error is `self.velocity = np.add(self.velocity + force * t / self.mass)`. You pass only 1 argument while you need to pass 2 arguments. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html